# Snap points to polygons based on attribute QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, fields-attributes, expression, snapping

I'd like to snap the points to the closest polygon (blocks) based on an attribute they share, this attribute is their suburb.

[image]

I've tried by running the following expression:

```
closest_point(
   geometry(get_feature('blocks','suburb',
   attribute( $currentfeature, 'suburb' ))),
   $geometry)
```

However, as you can see below, It snaps all the points to only one polygon per suburb when there are others that also have the same suburb and are closer. Does anyone know what should I modify in my expresion to make sure the process takes into account all the polygons??

[image]

Comment: Is your suburbs layer Polygon, or MultiPolygon?

Answer (score 1):

Better use [overlay_nearest()](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-nearest) function:

```
closest_point (
    eval (
        'overlay_nearest( 
            ''blocks'',  -- change to match the name of your polygon layer
            $geometry,
            filter:=suburb='  || sub ||  -- change names accordingly
        ')'
    ) [0],
    $geometry
)
```

Adapt these names if necessary:

- `blocks` is the name of the polygon layer (line 4)
- `suburb` is the name of the attribute on the polygon layer  (line 6)
- `sub` is the name of the attribute on the point layer  (line 6)

*Red points snapped to the nearest polygon with the same attribute value = white points, here created with geometry generator:*
[image]

Comment: that expression looks fantastic, I already executed it through geometry generator and geometry by expression but getting as a result a no-geometries shapefile, inspecting the attribute table it seems that no entries were lost but they just  don't display any geometry (point). The datasets I'm working with are massive, does it have something to do with this error?

Comment: Did you set output geometry type to point? Can you post a screenshot? Otherwise it's difficult to say

Comment: Did you adapt the names of the layer and fields correctly?